# Textview2 is not showm when TextView1 have more than one line

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have some problem when Textview1 have more than one line.

Example: textview1 have one line, textview2 is shown.

[image]

But if textview1 have more than one line, textview2 is not shown because textview1 is full.

[image]

And my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_vote"
                android:src="@drawable/vote_t_1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxdfkldjsklfjsdxxxxxx"
                android:id="@+id/tx_poll"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_vote"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ttt"
                android:id="@+id/tx_count_vote"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_count_poll"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_poll"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: use ellipsize on your textview

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using a relative layout here. I usually prefer using linear layouts in cases like these..

Comment: you can use `table-row` or `linearLayout` with weight properties.

Comment: @SRBbans How to use it ,please give example for me

Comment: @ARR.s see the answer.

Comment: @ARR.s see my answer below

Comment: add android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tx_count_vote" in your tx_poll

Comment: @AndreaEbano it's not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of having textviews side by side its always recommended to use Linear Layout with weight = 1 for both the textviews.

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"   
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewprimary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="abcd" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSecondary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="efgh" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks! if chage weight = 1 for both the textviews, it's not work, but
change android:layout_weight="1" with textview1 only ,it's work!

Comment: Yes tht's what I meant, i just roughly said weight. To illustrate what I meant I pasted the code which says "android:layout_weight". I'm happy that it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

wrap your textviews as tablerow.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_vote"
                android:src="@drawable/vote_t_1"/>

            <TableRow
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_vote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight=".60" // here manage the weight/percentage
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxdfkldjsklfjsdxxxxxx"
                android:id="@+id/tx_poll"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight=".40"// here manage the weight/percentage
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ttt"
                android:id="@+id/tx_count_vote"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_count_poll"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

            </TableRow> 


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks ,but if sometime textview have one line,this is problem for me to set textview (I want to set textview2 after textview1)

Comment: it will always be after on the right side of the textview 1.

Comment: umm but i want to textview2 is after last text in textview1

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_vote"
            android:src="@drawable/vote_t_1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_vote"
            android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="xxxxxxdfkldjsklfjsdxxxxxx"
            android:id="@+id/tx_poll"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ttt"
            android:id="@+id/tx_count_vote"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_count_poll"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have `android:layout_height="wrap_content`" on your `android:id="@+id/tx_poll"`. When there is a lot of text it shifts your `android:id="@+id/tx_count_vote"` and it becomes invisible.

You have this options:

1. Add fixed size for `tx_poll` TextView. Something like: `android:layout_width="90dp"`
2. Use LinearLayout with `layout_weight`
3. Use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the property android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tx_count_vote" in tx_poll and you can also set maxLength of the textView to prevent overlapping and fixing the area of tx_poll textView